# Getting undefined when tryin to read textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please for a reason, firstly this is not a duplicate i cant get to resolve this i am getting undefined when trying to read a textarea with an "e" attribute

```js
function naa(e) {
  var postida = $(e).attr('id');
  var comment = $("#not_" + postida).val(); //returns undefined textarea value
  alert(postida); //returns correct id value
  alert(comment); //returns undefined texarea value
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control comment jj" id="not_<?php echo $ch_file ?>" title="fileId" rows="3"></textarea>


<button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block wnana" id="fileId" onclick="naa(this)" style="margin-top:10px;">Add comment</button>

<!--run naa function when thr btn is clicked

I also tried

var comment =  $("#not_"+postida).text(); //returns undefined textarea value too
          
-->
```

Comment: Just as a comment, the function naa is not closed, so it won't be interpreted properly.

Comment: thanks edited please help me out @cnexans

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like for your `<textarea>` and `<button>`? Your `$ch_file` variable might not be valid for use in jQuery's *id* selector

Comment: @Phil i am trying to save comment through ajax hat is not really important for the post when i hit add comment i collect the id of the button clicked with function then i use that collected id to get the not id that is textarea value  var comment =  $("#not_"+postida).val();  with this var postida = $(e).attr('id'); but i keep getting undefined

Comment: @Phil - that's an amazing catch!! I was just testing the code - almost as is - assuming the value of `$ch_file` as `xyz`, and it appears to work correctly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmvBZy. So, it's quite likely that there may be some undesirable characters in the HTML rendered

Comment: @chiz In the `<textarea>`, please also try adding changing `id="not_<?php echo $ch_file ?>"` to `id="not_<?php echo $ch_file; ?>"` (i.e. terminating `echo` with a semicolon, not sure if that extra space is otherwise causing an issue)

Comment: @DhruvSaxena I checked your codepen replicated the code and if i call the id not_ it creates an undefined but if i alert only var postida it gives me the correct file type please what could be the problem

Comment: @DhruvSaxena still firing undefined what could be the issue for me the code is correct or could be the (e) because calling it without the (e) only the postida returns the correct id

Comment: @chiz I'm sorry, I couldn't quite follow your first comment. Do you mind creating your own codepen link and share so that the `undefined` error can be seen, please?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena Seen the error my echo file looks like this 00099998888iop334_.mp4 when i changed it caused an alert i created the correct value so it is those random text thanks now at least we know what to do next time

Comment: @chiz To be honest, I'm not sure if I understand what fixed the problem for you. However, if you've finally managed to get it working, then that's really good to hear! All the best.

Comment: Don't use a procedural Id this is BRITTLE! Use a class selector. You can pick any class you want, and its not going to break

Comment: Why would your button have a hard-coded `id`, but your textarea have a dynamic `id`, when your `naa()` function assumes that the textarea's `id` will be based on the button's? Unless `<?php echo $ch_file ?>` returns the string `"fileId"` the code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<textarea id="text_area_id" onclick="naa(this)"></textarea>

<script>
function naa(input) {
  var comment = $(input).val();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am catching an event and submitting data to ajax with the add comment button in the code above